# Proper name for a project supports 2 different release

Tags: terminology, maintenance, versioning, release-management

Is there a technical name for a software project where the current and prior stable releases are both maintained?

Answer (score 1):

The naming convention of such is usually determined by the source control system that you're using.  *SVN*, for example, uses the terms *branches* and *tags* to refer to its codebases, with the latter referring to previously closed versions.  My company refers to a branch of code for a previously released version as **maintenance branch**, although that may be individual of us.

Answer (score 1):

The general terminology for releases (see [Release Management Done Right](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Release-Management-Done-Right.aspx)) are:

- Active - describes a release that's currently in development (unreleased)
- Latest - the "highest" release available
- Previous - anything other than the Latest Release

So, 4.0 is the latest, while 3.0 and 3.1 are previous. Most software has a linear release pattern (this is significantly easier to maintain obviously): 3.0 first, then 3.1, then 4.0.

The non-linear pattern you describe (3.0 first, then 4.0, *then* 3.1) is called  **Previous Release Support**. In this case, 4.0 remains the *Latest* release, even though 3.1 shipped after as a fix for 3.0 users.

Microsoft follows this pattern (Windows XP, a *previous* release is continually supported), whereas Apple (I believe), does not - you always have to upgrade to latest.